# Why Tasker can't recognize WIFI SSID

Tags: tasker

After I changed my device and import the tasker's profiles from the old Samsung to the new one (Huawei), the "Wifi connected" state can't recognize the SSID any longer.

I can confirm it's related to the SSID, I've created a simple profile detecting WIFI state only, and if I don't put any name in "SSID" field, the profile get green when the wifi is connected, and the profile with SSID still gray.

And it's also strange that, some times, while a turn on the wifi, the profile turned green, and maybe one second or two, it turns to gray again.

Comment: If your device is running Android 8 or 9 you are affected by the new system policy that [throttles Wifi SSID scanning](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-throttling). May be what you observe are the consequences of this policy.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the information, very helpful. seems like that is the problem, the new phone indeed has Android 9 installed, and not the old one. So the new question will be: is there ways to reduce the wifi scan times of Tasker.

Answer (score 0):

I think we're going to need some more information; always good practice whenever troubleshooting any system, look at the log files.

Switch on logging for Tasker using the instructions here: https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/faqs/faq-how.html#x2

Set up your profile with no SSID name so you get a green profile, toggle the wifi off and back on again, then look at the log file.

Then set up your profile with your failing SSID name, toggle the wifi again, look at the log again.

Are there any obvious differences or error messages which start to point us in the right direction?

Comment: thanks for the tips. I've run the log, and there's no interesting message in it. I think it is related the wifi scanning throttles as @Robert mentioned in question comment.